# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3906.00'

Tags: python, pandas

Unable to parse string "3,906.00" at position 0
I tried:

```
df["sales"]=df["sales"].str.replace(",","").astype(int)
```

then ,it turns out this:

```
Unable to parse string "3906.00" at position 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df["sales"]=df["sales"].str.replace(",","").astype(float).astype(int)
```